# How can I fix the CORS error "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present"?

Tags: javascript, react-native, cors

I'm currently learning to code and for the love of god can't figure out this issue.
Following the instructions, my current server side js code looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Models = require('./models.js');
const passport = require('passport');
require('./passport');
const Movies = Models.Movie;
const Users = Models.User;
const express = require('express'),
      morgan = require('morgan'),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
      uuid = require('uuid/v5');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const { check,validationResult} = require('express-validator');

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://' + process.env.Userpass + '@darksdb-dkyuz.mongodb.net/darksdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
})

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(morgan('common'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var allowedOrigins = ['*'];

app.use(
    cors({
         origin: function (origin, callback) {
              if (!origin) return callback(null, true);
              if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1) {
                  // if specific origin isn't found on list of allowed origins
                  var message =
                      'The CORS policy for this application doesn´t allow access from origin' +
                      origin;
                  return callback(new Error(message), false);
              }
              return callback(null, true);
          }
    })
);

var auth = require('./auth')(app);

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send('Oops! Sorry about that, something went wrong!');
});
```

Each time I try to register a new user, I get this response:

> **Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/limitless-thicket-23479/users' from origin 'http://localhost:1234' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

I'm pretty sure I've done something wrong but, being so new to this, I have no idea where I have gone wrong in order to start trouble shooting. Some suggestions I've read would require me to change code I'm already unfamiliar with and I feel I'd break this even more if I start to just "wing it".

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thank you

PS: apologies if my tags are misleading or wrong, I'm still learning :/

Comment: @HereticMonkey, he has already implemented the cors property but only the thing missing that i found missing is not registered core into app.

Comment: ... I'm sure there's a duplicate of that too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't adding CORS headers to an OPTIONS route allow browsers to access my API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7067966/215552)

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38500226/441757 — in particular the part with `app.options('*', cors())`. And see the docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Answer (score -1):

Hi i think before routing you should use below mentioned code.

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Hope this will solve your question.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but, where should I add this?